# ¿Se usa "halar" en vez de "jalar" en algún lugar?

Tags: diferencias-regionales

En Estados Unidos veo muy frecuentemente traducciones que usan la horrorosa `halar` en lugar de `jalar` (o `hale aquí`, etc.)

Es tan común que me imagino debe ser usado así en algún lugar. En caso afirmativo, ¿dónde? En caso negativo, ¿saben si hay una tendencia a aceptar esta variante?

Comment: En Cuba se usa mucho.

Comment: @deStrangis De hecho en Cuba de niños solían decirnos en la escuela que "jalar" era incorrecto. No se si continua siendo así. Me resulta muy gracioso ahora que alguien lo encuentre "horroroso".

Comment: Entiendo que el uso de "halar" en lugar de "jalar" se refiere tanto a la escritura como a la pronunciación, ¿no? (¿o acaso algunos escriben "halar" y pronuncian "jalar"?)

Comment: Muy en desacuerdo con tu comentario. En México pronunciamos y escribimos jalar. Pero lo más importante, nunca pronunciamos la "h" como "j"... ¡Nunca!
Los americanos dicen "La Jacienda", para decir "La Hacienda"... Para nosotros en México siempre la "H" será complemamente muda.

Comment: No es cierto no siempre es muda, poco a poco con el contacto con otros idiomas nos vamos dando cuenta cuando se pronuncia o cuando no.

Comment: Nunca lo habia visto con J hasta que vine a FLorida. Por lo tanto me choca cada vez que lo veo.

Comment: Nunca escuché que fuera horroroso usar la forma "halar", al contrario siempre mis profesores de español me enseñaron que no dijera "jalar" porque era incorrecto. Quizás el roce con otros idiomas, dígase Inglés, hizo que la "h"comenzara a pronunciarse como "j".

Comment: Que interesante ver que dicen jalar en vez de halar en Mexico y les molesta que los americanos dicen j(h)acienda (aunque no sea su lengua natal), pero al parecer no les molesta ecribir Mexico y decir Méjico.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según la RAE, *jalar* deriva de *halar*, que a su vez procede del francés *haler*. Por tanto, no es que haya una tendencia a aceptar una variante, sino que es la palabra original. Otra cosa es que en según qué lugares sea más habitual una palabra u otra.

Comment: También depende de el significado que se le dé. Aunque _jalar_ deriva de _halar_, con el tiempo han tenido algunas diferencias de siginficado. Personalmente yo conozco _jalar_ con el siginficado de comer rápido y mucho. No conocía _halar_ hasta ahora, pero viendo las definiciones, no incluye la que se refiere a comer.

Comment: @Pablo Ciertamente, no tienen los mismos significados (sobre todo los significados coloquiales, como el que mencionas). Lo que quiero decir es que no es una variante nueva sino que la palabra *halar* es anterior a *jalar*. En el sentido que se menciona en la pregunta sí que se usa, según el DRAE, en diversos países, sobre todo de Centroamérica.

Answer (score 2):

En algunos países hispanohablantes se distingue el sonido de la *h* aspirada (similar al inglés) del de la *j* (más velar o uvular; como en inglés *loch*).  Dado que son pocas las palabras que usan *h* aspirada en español (*halar*, *harto*, *Helsinki*) la distinción se pierde.

El término más correcto y original es *halar*, pronunciado con *h* aspirada, y si en tu acento propio no distingues la *h* aspirada de la *j*, se pronuncia entonces como *jalar*.  La escritura con *h* es por lo tanto correcta aún cuando se pronuncia como *j*.

Comment: No coincido en indicar "más correcto", o es correcto o no lo es, sin embargo se puede decir a "más común" o "menos común". Ambos términos son correctos aunque (personalmente) he escuchado más la pronunciación con  j que con h.

Answer (score 0):

Lo vi mucho durante mi tiempo en Nicaragua. Se ve "hale aquí" en las puertas de los centros comerciales, restaurantes, bancos, etcétera.

Answer (score -1):

En España halar es correcto (pero poco usado) y jalar es simplemente incorrecto.

Comment: [¿Incorrecto?](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=jalar)

Comment: El DRAE lo marca como "coloquial", lo que lo hace impropio de la norma culta.

Comment: *Coloquial* e *incorrecto* son dos cosas muy diferentes.

Answer (score -2):

En México usamos " JALAR " siempre con jota y se pronuncia igual con jota como jamón.
La hache H siempre es mucha solo en combinación con la C como el nombre de la letra.
Me molesta mucho escuchar en la televisión programas doblados del inglés, donde dicen (h)alen o (h)ala esa cuerda. En vez de decir jalen o jala esa cuerda.
La Real Academia de Lengua Española, es una porquería.